# This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type unit -> bool

Tags: recursion, ocaml, anonymous-function

my perpose (I wrote this explain  after question and best answer) :
I wanted to call each different function case token of char with read string. So, just I wanted to do do is loop function that call each different function drives the char.

---

I'm OCaml beginner. I try to call function from anonymous function.
But error occured in calling function in anonymous function with function keyword.
I have no idea. How to make it work in OCaml?

Here is error code.

```
This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type unit -> bool
```

Here is my noob code with placing of error emphasised with ^^^.

```
let parseS () =
  false

let parseZ () =
  false

type parenType = Open_paren | Close_paren

let parseParen = function
  | (Open_paren)  -> ()
  | (Close_paren) -> ()

let read_input (str:string) () =
  let len = String.length str in
  let i = 0 in
  let rec read_token = function
    | (current, chr) when current >= len -> parseZ
    | (current, chr) when chr = 'S' -> parseS
    | (current, chr) when chr = 'Z' -> parseZ
    | (current, chr) when chr = '(' -> parseParen Open_paren
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
    | (current, chr) when chr = ')' -> parseParen Close_paren
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
    | _ -> raise @@ Invalid_argument "Error cause with token "
  in
  read_token (i + 1, str . [i + 1]) ;;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions `parseZ` and `parseS` both have type `unit -> bool`. The expression `parseParen Open_paren` is of type `unit`. Since you put both `parseZ` and `parseParen Open_paren` in the same place of your pattern matching, they are inferred to be of the same type, which cannot work since `unit -> bool` and `unit` are obviously two different types.

I notice that your function `read_token` is declared as recursive yet not used recursively. Maybe you want to modify the right-hand sides of your pattern matching to do what you want to do ?

Comment: > Maybe you want to modify the right-hand sides of your pattern matching to do what you want to do ?

Yes I think so. I want to use this `read_token` to call function whatever it return type . I can't still understand why Is it work to fix same type of return type.

 I think this `read_token` work recursively with code `in read_token (i + 1, str . [i + 1] )` . But maybe not work since not appropriate function used.

Comment: I try to fix by change type of return `parseZ` and `parseS` to anonymous function. The error code is change with here `This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type unit -> unit Hint: Did you forget to wrap the expression using `fun () ->'?`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, and what your different functions are supposed to do. Maybe if edit your question to explain what you're attempting to write and how, we can help you better. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I will write explain what I  wanted just to for people looking after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try code moves for the time being about func `read_input`. `read_input` return same type it call other function and after anonymous function.

```
let read_input (str:string) =
  let len = String.length str in
  for i = 0 to len - 1 do
    match str . [i] with
    | 'S' -> parseS ()
    | 'Z' -> parseZ ()
    | '(' -> parseParen Open_paren
    | ')' -> parseParen Close_paren
    | _ -> ()
  done
```